# How to prevent accidental modification of an array from the method? Without making the array immutable

Tags: c#, arrays

In the following method, how can I prevent the contents of my array from being modified accidentally or otherwise?

Can it be done without changing the array to another type, such as a list?

```
    public static int LinearSearch(int[] myArray, int target)
    {
        int idx = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myArray[i] == target) { idx = i; break; }
        }
        return idx;
    }
```

Comment: The question has been edited. Can the "duplicate" tag be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ImmutableArray<T>` class.

> Provides methods for creating an array that is immutable; meaning it cannot be changed once it is created.

For instance:

```
ImmutableArray<int> array = ImmutableArray.Create(1, 2, 3);
```

You can also try the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` class, that doesn't include a `.Add` method.

Comment: This solution puts a burden on the user of OPs method to only pass ImmutableArray references.